# SharpGL / OpenGL WPF

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

I started studying SharpGL on WPF, and I wanted to learn how to output a picture, I found a tutorial where it was shown how to output a picture, but after rewriting the code to myself, the picture is not output, but output a red image, what could be wrong?
[Wpf screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHVJG.png)

[Link to Download Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WK38mQa3WKAACpLp1PP3RCi1yONgDTHi/view?usp=sharing)

```
 Texture texture = new Texture();
    private void openGLControl1_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Get the OpenGL object, for quick access.
        SharpGL.OpenGL gl = this.openGLControl1.OpenGL;
        //  Get the OpenGL object, for quick access.


        //  A bit of extra initialisation here, we have to enable textures.
        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        //  Create our texture object from a file. This creates the texture for OpenGL.
        texture.Create(gl, @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Crate.bmp");

    }
 

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SharpGL.OpenGL gl = this.openGLControl1.OpenGL;

        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        texture.Bind(gl);
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Translate(0, 0, -1f);


        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_QUADS);

        var startX = 0 - 0 / 2;
        var startY = 0 - 0 / 2;

        float width = 100;
        float height = 100;

        gl.TexCoord(0, 1); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX, startY });
        gl.TexCoord(1, 1); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX + width, startY });
        gl.TexCoord(1, 0); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX + width, startY + height });
        gl.TexCoord(0, 0); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX, startY + height });

        gl.End();

        gl.Flush();
    }


    private void OpenGLControl_Resized(object sender, OpenGLRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        SharpGL.OpenGL gl = this.openGLControl1.OpenGL;
        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        float w = 450;
        float h = w * 0.5625f;
        gl.Viewport(0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);

        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```